# Cannot import modules from different folders

Tags: python

For a project I have a script that has to import a module from a different folder.
My file structure is the following:

[image]

The code in script.py is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from algorithms.kmeans.kmeans import *

representatives = ["WestVlaanderen", "Hainaut", "Brussels", "BrabantWallon"]

representatives_info = pd.read_csv("data\\filtered_data\KMEANS.csv")

representatives_info = representatives_info[representatives_info["PROVINCE"].isin(representatives)]
representatives_info = representatives_info[["INFECTION_RATE", "HOSPITALISATION_RATE", "TEST_POS_PERCENTAGE"]].to_numpy()

kmeans = Kmeans("data\filtered_data\KMEANS.csv", 4, representatives_info)
kmeans.start_clustering()
```

Both the folder algorithms and kmeans both have their own **init**.py file (empty but I read that this doesn't matter). And I still can't import the wanted file.

The error I get is:

> No module named 'algorithms'

When I try using the same import on the python interactive mode in my bash terminal it works without errors. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong for the import not to work

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using visual studio code